# Why can't Stack Overflow have links opening new tabs, a fixed topbar, better background colors, and "favorite user" lists?

Tags: feature-request, design

1. Why can't *hyperlinks* be set to *target="_blank"*? Clicking the back button is *scary* most especially if you are going back to continue from where you stopped.
2. Why is the *topbar* not set to *fixed*? This carries my details, user details and should be readily available to me however deep the valley.
3. Why is the *background color* of *Favorite Tags* set to *#ffefc6*? The color is dull, it's not receptive and doesn't encourage learning. It kills ones creativity. Dead leaves aren't attractive. All these are IMHO.
4. And why can't I be able to favorite *users*?

*These are the little things that matter - to me.*

Comment: Q1: target="_blank" has been defined by many UX analysis to be a bad user journey.

Comment: All of this except maybe point 3 has been discussed before. (1) - because the user should be able to control where a link opens, use middle-click to open in a new tab. (2) - I don't recall the exact reasons but there were only a few arguments _for_ it and many against. (4) - SO is _not_ a social network, focus on content, not on users. You can still subscribe to a users RSS feed.

Comment: If you make a feature request, keep it to one request per question. And please don't abuse code formatting for things that aren't really code.

Comment: @Bart I rather have it in one, that only requires me to post and edit one answer instead of 4...

Comment: So what should we mark it if only one of the requests gets completed @rene? Status-semi-completed? And how do you find this post as a duplicate? Based on its awesomely descriptive title? Nah, one request, one post.

Comment: For you @Bart, a better and more descriptive title has been provided. And status will be status-declined for all

Comment: @bart [status-declined](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umDr0mPuyQc)

Comment: Some of these answers are good but not acceptable. Some are just rude. Vote it down as many times as you may want. I have asked a simple question, and however poor it may look, the question seeks educative answers. You can argue that SO is a Q&A site and about content but presentation matters. It does!

Comment: A down vote on meta doesn't mean it's a bad question (although it isn't great), it simply means that users don't think that your suggestions will bring any benefits to the site.

Comment: What makes favouriting a user a Social Networking feature? What makes good background color a Social Networking feature? What differentiate favouriting a question and user? Are the two not all about the things I want to be reminded of often?

Comment: It's a Q&A site, which is not user centric. The focus is on the content not the users.

Comment: @Tanner: That doesn't make sense to me. I repeat, Presentation Matters even in a content-centric site. SO allows differentiation of content.

Comment: If you are intent on 'connecting' a lot of users have websites on their profile or twitter usernames in their bio but the answers already cover this issue.

Comment: Q1: why can't you just use the middle mouse button? Works in all three major browsers, should work for you. Unless you are using some old/eclectic system.

Comment: You can subscribe to a user's rss feed.  Look for the "user feed" link at the bottom of the profile page.

Comment: While the question has been heavily downvoted, I agree with point #3. It hurts my eyes. Yes, I can customize my browser, but if the majority dislike the color (and maybe they don't), then there is no reason to leave an ugly color by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. 2. 3.** Depending on the browser you use, you can simply install a userstyle extension and code a userstyle for all Stack Overflow pages. You can even publish it on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) for other users to use if appropiate. There is no pressing need to implement this, *and* no consensus has been made that these little things are bugging anyone else, if at all a problem.

**4.** Already discussed aspects against this on these threads:

[Answer for "Is there any friend system on Stack Overflow?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118383/266094) - by [Nick Craver♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver)

> > As far as I know, Stack Overflow is positioned as a bit social networking service.
>
> ....no, no we aren't. If this happens, go ahead and send someone over to shoot me.
>
> I kid, but no, social networking isn't what we're about, there are already sites for that. We're about the *content*, not the *user*.

[Answer for "Private Message Feature"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4833/266094) - by [GEOCHET](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/5640/geochet)

> SO.com is not a social site. It is a programming Q&A site. No thanks.

Comment: Fair and educative enough.

Answer (score 15):

I'll address your points but as they are all asked before on Meta.SE I won't repeat the reasons why we can't have them, instead I picked the most notable answers from Marc Gravell, Toomai, Conkerchen and cletus.

1. [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window) [*Just hold down Ctrl when you click*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2276/158100)
2. [previous discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional) [*How many people loathe headers and footers that follow you around as you scroll?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142205/158100)
3. [Have your own CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166306/change-background-color-of-the-favorite-tags-questions) [*You could use custom css in your browser*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166310/158100)
4. [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice) [*Repeat after me: SO is not a social networking site.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/158100)

There is [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) (*Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch is a project to collect various minor client-side bug fixes*) that tries to incorperate little improvements to the UI. You might try to see what they already have or propose a patch that implement your requests.

Comment: I suspect (4) is probably by-design since SO is a Q&A site first and a community far second.

Comment: @Paul addressed that as well.. thanks...

Comment: SO is not a social networking site

Comment: Despite this being the rude answer I might get a populist badge for it....