# How to add "target='_blank'" to a hyperlink on an answer?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I want to write an answer but I can't find a way to include a link to another answer and have that link to open in a new tab of the browser.

I don't know where to put the `target="_blank" property to the link. I have searched on Stack Overflow help but found nothing.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Why is that function crucial for your answer?

Comment: In six years of using Stack Overflow I've never heard of anyone missing this feature.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Apparently [someone else wanted it a year ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276662/why-cant-stack-overflow-have-links-opening-new-tabs-a-fixed-topbar-better-bac?lq=1)

Comment: @NicolBolas I *did* actually think of that one before posting :) But as far as I can see, that request is about making links in the UI target=_blank, or all links - it seems a bit unclear. Either way, it doesn't seem to be about extending markdown in the editor so users can control how their links open.

Comment: I don't understand why you voted down a question? It's just a question, not a bad answer that cause confusion to other users or something like that...

Comment: This is crucial for usability. A link to a codepen that opens in the same window? Bad usability!!! Makes me want to smash my mouse through my screen. This should be fixed.

Comment: Note that this question currently has 6 upvotes and 8 downvotes. This could mean that a significant amount of people feel the same frustration I do. The downvoters are just downvoting a reasonable request IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. The markdown parser and allowed html tags are very strict.

From [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100)

> #### a Attributes
>
> The following attributes are allowed on the `<a>` tag:
>
> ```
> href=""  
> title=""
> ```
>
> #### Important Notes
>
> - HTML tags unlisted above are stripped from the output. They may render in the client preview, but they will always be removed on the server.
> - You must enter the tags exactly as shown. Any deviation from this list—adding extra spaces, using single quote or no quotes, etc.—means the tag will be stripped.

Based on the above guidance you'll learn that if you add a `target='blank'` to your `<a href="awesomeanswer">` it will be stripped. So you can not achieve what you want.

There are some [feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309971/on-click-open-image-link-to-the-next-tab) to [change or add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276662/why-cant-stack-overflow-have-links-opening-new-tabs-a-fixed-topbar-better-bac) this but they are either declined or down voted. Or even better [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Answer (score -3):

It all depends on the markdown.  I looked around and found this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank).  You could also try doing {:target="_blank"} at the end of the markdown, but as far as I can tell- it isn't something you can do on Stack.  Just tell em to ctrl-click it!

Comment: Thanks Gray, I will try your idea...